# Which one is better, 3 ServerSocket each processing 1 requests OR 1 ServerSocket process 3 requests

Tags: java, sockets

I want to write an application in Java which will receive three requests at the same time continuously, then in the figure below which way is better and why to write the code or is there any other way better then these two? Thanks
   [image]

Comment: You may want to take a look at netty.io

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It hardly makes any difference. All the activity with the `ServerSocket` itself is concerned with accepting connections and starting threads. There's no need for three `ServerSockets` and three threads to do this. In any case as they will all be listening to different ports, which one gets used is determined by the client, so it's pretty pointless: all clients could end up using only one of the `ServerSockets.`

Comment: The first one appears quite absurd, don't know who upvoted it!

Comment: Because there are fixed three requests all coming from three different machine for three different purposes, then in the first one every thread is listening to their own port and process their own request, so there is no need every time we check what this request is and new an New thread to process. But the second (which I am using now) need to create a new thread for a new request every time to process, if we process it in the same thread it will take time then the next request will wait for the previous request for finish execution. So the first is good to avoid every time create new thread.

Answer (score 2):

If for each Request the processing of the request is same, then it is better that you use the same port with multiple threads to process it.

The usual practice is that for each functionality to have a different port in a system. For example FTP - Not Secured, SFTP - Secured.